# convert bitset to ASCII String

Tags: c++, string, bitset

How do you convert back a binary to string?

```
std::string test1("Hello");
std::bitset<8> test2;
test2 = std::bitset<8>(test1.c_str()[0]);

std::cout << test2 << std::endl;
std::string test3=test2.to_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(); 
std::cout << test3 << std::endl;
```

This will output:
01001000
01001000

How do i output back "Hello"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `std::bitset<8>` clearly can't hold the world `"Hello"`. After all, you are only representing 8 bits. What you can do is to convert each `char` to a `std::bitset<8>` (assuming `char` is 8 bit, of course, which is typically the case but not guaranteed) and the `std::bitset<8>` back to its value as an integer using `to_ulong()`. Converting this value thus obtained to `char` should yield the original character:

```
std::bitset<8> c(test1[0]);
std::cout << "c=" << c << " char(c.to_ulong())=" << char(c.to_ulong()) << "\n";
```

To get `"Hello"` back you'd need a bigger `std::bitset<N>` and you'd need to make sure you extract the correct bits to reassemble the correct individual character.

Comment: If you are not sure about N in `std::bitset<N>` you can use `boost::dynamic_bitset`